# Can an eigenbasis be divided into bases of the eigenspaces?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators, schauder-basis

I am considering an operator $A$ defined on a subspace of some Hilbert space $H$ and I am given a Hilbert-basis $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that all $v_n$ are eigenvectors of $A$:
$$Av_n=\lambda v_n$$
I am wondering whether the basis can be divided into bases of the eigenspaces, possibly under additional assumptions (e.g. $A$ compact and symmetric). The equivalance relation is obvious:
$$v_i\sim v_j:\Leftrightarrow\lambda_i=\lambda_j$$ But how do I know that each eigenspace is spanned by an equivalence class? The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4685618/572841) suggest that the issue is subtle.